# Asp.net web api input property type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have defined my api with resource products:

```
public class Product
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }        
 }
```

submitting following json requests:

1. { "Id": 4}
2. { "Id": "4"}

In both cases succeeds. Is it expected behavior not to throw a exception in case when the string is a valid integer during binding?

Comment: No it is. The model binder will be able to use the string "4" to bind to the integer Id property.

Answer (score 0):

The binding can resolve those types automatically. It will only be a problem if there's a value inside that list bigger than Int32.MaxValue(2,147,483,647).

Comment: what would be a solution to enforce the type?

Comment: As I said, you dont need to enforce "4" from json to 4 integer since the model binder can convert it. But if you want to enforce the conversion to Int32, you can do that by creating a custom modelbinder and applying Convert.ToInt32(value).